# PowerQuery / multiply many columns with a single column / shift up results without blank(null)

Tags: powerquery

First of all, sorry for my broken English. If something might feel offence, that is my fault. Sorry (and Thanks) in advance.

As title said, I want to get a way how to multiply many rows with one single row in one step: regardless how many columns and whatever column name is, & ignore blank cells then shift up filled results in POWERQUERY.

[image]

0. want to get a final table in yellow, with merging Ratio table and Total table.
1. want to know how to multiply Ratio table (many columns) and Total table (a single column) in one step.
2. From Grey table, want to get a way how to remove null value and shift up filled results.
3. prefer "Transform" than "Add column".

if you need an example file, can get it via this link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/fs2cymeak1f2w57/powerquery%20practice.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: This is not what powerquery is made for.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like you're asking the internet to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im 99% certain Im doing homework for someone, but anyway

Unpivot Ratio. Merge in Total, multiply with custom column. Group on Attribute and add index. Pivot

```
let Source = Ratio,
// I am too lazy to do my own homework and should be ashamed
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"M"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Value] <> 0)),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filtered Rows1", {"M"}, Total, {"Month"}, "Total", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Total" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Total", {"Total"}, {"Total"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Total", "Custom", each if [Total]=null then 0 else [Total]*[Value]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Value", "Total","M"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Attribute"}, {{"data", each  Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Month", 1, 1, Int64.Type), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", { "Custom", "Month"}, { "Custom", "Month"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded data", List.Distinct(#"Expanded data"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Custom")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a very beginner, and not familiar with stack overflow's culture.
But I'm sorry if you think it is homework. 

I just want to know more efficient way and have less step to get the final results, specially use List.something formula. which I am good at handling on. (I might think I need to use List. formula for it.)

However, I'm appreciated with your work and have to say thank you.

Comment: You should mark this as solved if the question has been answered.